# Module or main program array must have constant shape error in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

An integer variable declared in the module is used as a global variable to define the size of related arrays in the program. The size of program varies, so the size of array is a variable but not a parameter. It is determined at the beginning of the program.

In the following snippet of code, `n` is the global size variable. It is declared in the module and defined at the beginning of main function/program. Similar usage of `n` in the main program and the subroutine contained in the main program to initialise an array respectively. However, the initialisation in the main program causes the error: module or main program array must have constant shape error, but the initialisation in subroutine works. What is the mechanism behind this different treatment of non-constant values used in different positions?

```
module mod
  implicit none
  integer :: n
end module mod



program main
  use mod
  implicit none
  integer :: b(n)
  n = 5
  b(:) = 1
  print*, b(:)

  call sub

contains

  subroutine sub
    integer :: a(n)
    a = 10
    print*, a
  end subroutine sub

end program main
```

Comment: The value of n is unknown at the moment of the declaration of integer :: b(n), so you should use something like: integer, pointer : b(:);     n = 5;     allocate(b) or integer, parameter :: nn = 5;     integer :: a(nn);     n = nn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array declared like `a(n)` is an *explicit shape* array.  When `n` is not a constant (named or otherwise, strictly a constant expression) such an array is an *automatic object*.

Automatic objects are restricted in where they may appear.  In particular, an explicit shape array is subject to the following constraint (C531 of F2008):

> An explicit-shape-spec whose bounds are not constant expressions shall appear only in a subprogram, derived type definition, BLOCK construct, or interface body.

As `n` from the module `mod` is not a constant it cannot be used as bounds of an array in the main program.  The subroutine `sub` is a subprogram and so `a(n)` is a valid use of a non-constant bound.

Instead of having an automatic object in the main program, one can instead consider *deferred shape* arrays, using either `pointer` or `allocatable` attributes.