# What is the point of BLOCK in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am looking at some code and there is this:

```
BLOCK

...lines of code...

END BLOCK
```

What is the purpose of `BLOCK`? I tried to google it, but all I found was something about `BLOCK DATA` and `COMMON` blocks. I'm not sure whether they are related.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH4D_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.aix.doc/language_ref/blockcon.html ?

Comment: By the way, for Google search, you can use `-` to exclude some words, such as `fortran BLOCK -DATA`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Fortran 2008 standard:

> The BLOCK construct is an executable construct that may contain declarations.

It is not related to common blocks or to block data program units.

So, the main use is this "containing declarations".

As scoping units we have things like

```
integer i
block
  integer j ! A local integer
  integer i ! Another i
  save i    ! ... which can even be SAVEd
end block
```

which affords locality of declarations:

```
! ... lots of code
block
  integer something
  read *, something
end block
! ... lots more code
```

These scoping blocks allow [automatic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45711764/3157076):

```
integer i
i = 5
block
  real x(i)
end block
```

As executable constructs, they also have useful [flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553892/3157076):

```
this_block: block
  if (something) exit this_block
  ! ... lots of code
end block
```

They also have finalization control:

```
type(t) x
block
  type(t) y
end block ! y is finalized
end  ! x is not finalized
```

for `x` and `y` of finalizable type.

Oh, and let's not forget how you can confuse people with implicit typing.

Comment: Nice remark "Oh, and let's not forget how you can confuse people with implicit typing."

Comment: @ripero thanks for reading and suggesting an edit.  In this case, however, "common" and "block data" are used in the natural language sense (see as written in the Fortran standards documents) and not as the Fortran statements (which would indeed use code fragment markdown).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong edit. By the way, could you clarify why, in the finalization control example, `x` is not finalized at the `end` statement after the `end block`? I understand that at the `end block` only variables declared inside of the block such as `y` will be finalized, so `x` will not be finalized there, but I would have expected `x` to be finalized once an `end` statement is reached.

Comment: @ripero, not a problem.  Regarding `x` not being finalized, that is just how Fortran is defined.  In F2008 you can see an explicit statement in 4.5.6.4.

Comment: @francescalus: ok, I had stopped reading at 4.5.6.3.  So in your example the `end` is an `end program`, but if it was an `end function` or an `end subroutine` then `x` would be finalised (if it was not a dummy argument, a function result, or `SAVE`d)?

Comment: @ripero, for `x` an unsaved local variable of the procedure, yes.

Comment: @francescalus: OK, thank you - second bit of Fortran that you led me to learn today!

Answer (score 10):

I have composed a few more fun examples. What if you want to invoke an `assumed length function` with different `lengths` in the same instance of a subprogram? You need a `specification statement` to tell the compiler the length you want, so a `BLOCK` construct can do this for you

```
function F(x)
   implicit none
   character(*) F
   character x(:)
   integer i
   do i = 1, len(F)
      F(i:i) = x(1)
   end do
end function F

program blox1
   implicit none
   integer i
   character c
   do i = 1, 7
      c = achar(65+modulo(i**4+6*i**2+1,26))
      block
         character(2*i+1), external :: F
         call blox1a(F)
      end block
   end do
   contains
      subroutine blox1a(F)
         interface
            function F(x)
               import
               implicit none
               character(2*i+1) F
               character x(:)
            end function F
         end interface
         write(*,'(a)') F([c])
      end subroutine blox1a
end program blox1
```

Output with `gfortran`:

```
III
PPPPP
GGGGGGG
PPPPPPPPP
WWWWWWWWWWW
FFFFFFFFFFFFF
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
```

Or how about when you need the appropriate `KIND` for a `REAL literal`? This requires a `named constant` and the `KIND` might be given in the `specification statements` of another `MODULE` and may even be given as an `expression`. In that case you might try defining a `named constant` with the value of that `expression`, but if an unlucky choice is made that name might override another `host associated` name. A `BLOCK` construct makes it all OK:

```
module mytypes
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   type T(KIND)
      integer, kind :: KIND
      real(KIND) x
   end type T
   interface assignment(=)
      module procedure assign8, assign4
   end interface assignment(=)
   contains
      subroutine assign8(x,y)
         real(REAL64), intent(in) :: y
         type(T(kind(y))), intent(out) :: x
         x%x = y
      end subroutine assign8
      subroutine assign4(x,y)
         real(REAL32), intent(in) :: y
         type(T(kind(y))), intent(out) :: x
         x%x = y
      end subroutine assign4
end module mytypes

program blox2
   use mytypes
   implicit none
   type(T(REAL32)) x
BLOCK
!   integer, parameter :: rk = x%KIND ! Not allowed
   integer, parameter :: rk = kind(x%x)
   x = 0.0072973525664_rk
   write(*,'(g0)') x%x
END BLOCK    -1 is too small
12! = 479001600
13 is too big
BLOCK
   type(T(REAL64)) x
BLOCK
!   integer, parameter :: rk = x%KIND ! Not allowed
   integer, parameter :: rk = kind(x%x)
   x = 0.0072973525664_rk
   write(*,'(g0)') x%x
END BLOCK
END BLOCK
end program blox2
```

Output with `gfortran`:

```
0.729735242E-02
0.72973525663999998E-002
```

It can be tricky to get a `Fortran pointer` to a `C string` because there is no syntax to tell `C_F_POINTER` what the `length` of the `target` of a `deferred length pointer` should be. `BLOCK` to the rescue!

```
program blox3
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   implicit none
   character(len=:,kind=C_CHAR), allocatable, target :: x
   type(C_PTR) c_hello
   integer(C_INTPTR_T) address
   character(kind=C_CHAR), pointer :: nul_address
   character(len=:,kind=C_CHAR), pointer :: f_hello
   integer i

   x = 'Hello, world'//achar(0)
   c_hello = C_LOC(x(1:1))
   address = transfer(c_hello,address)
   i = 0
   do
      call C_F_POINTER(transfer(address+i,C_NULL_PTR),nul_address)
      if(nul_address == C_NULL_CHAR) exit
      i = i+1
   end do
BLOCK
   character(len=i,kind=C_CHAR), pointer :: temp
   call C_F_POINTER(c_hello,temp)
   f_hello => temp
END BLOCK
write(*,'(i0,1x,a)') len(f_hello), f_hello
end program blox3
```

Output with `gfortran`:

```
12 Hello, world
```

Not to mention that a `named BLOCK construct` gives us a `label` to hang our `spaghetti code` on:

```
program blox4
   implicit none
   integer i
   integer j(3)
   integer k

   j = [-1,12,13]
do i = 1, size(j)
factorial: BLOCK
   if(j(i) < 0) then
      write(*,'(*(g0))') j(i),' is too small'
      EXIT factorial
   end if
   if(j(i) > 12) then
      write(*,'(*(g0))') j(i),' is too big'
      EXIT factorial
   end if
   write(*,'(*(g0))') j(i),'! = ',product([(k,k=1,j(i))])
END BLOCK factorial
end do
end program blox4
```

Output with `gfortran`:

```
-1 is too small
12! = 479001600
13 is too big
```

Comment: @francescalus What's the problem? `ifort` and `gfortran` both warn about the use of obsolescent `assumed length character function` but if it's not deleted, it's not invalid. Is there a problem both compilers are missing with `Fortran 2008` standards checking in force?

Comment: Because you use an interface block the characteristics for the external function given there must be consistent with those of the function's definition.  In this case, the defined function has assumed length character function result, but the interface block says something different.  Now, if you used `character(2*i+1) F` instead...

Comment: @francescalus Apparently we view the world through different-colored glasses so we might have to agree to disagree once again. However, I made an edit wearing your optical aids. Hope you like it :)

Comment: What I meant (comments, especially those typed on a tram aren't best for this level of discussion), was that `block; character(2*i+1) F; write(*,'(a)') F(c); end block` would have worked.  Hopefully that's (slightly) clearer.

Comment: @francescalus But that's not relevant to my edit where an explicit interface is required.

Comment: `If used to specify the character length parameter of a function result, any scoping unit invoking the function or passing it as an actual argument shall declare the function name with a character length parameter value other than * or access such a definition by argument, host, or use association. When the function is invoked, the length of the function result is assumed from the value of this type parameter.` So by the time `subroutine blox1` gets it, the length has already been assumed. I know you don't see it like this, but I thought I would let you see the logic of my position.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your reasoning.  I now see what you intend and `blox1a` is certainly more subtle.  I am now currently undecided and will give my Fortran processor a rest before looking again.

Comment: Right, I _think_ it's not valid (but there are several options for minor changes that make it so).  Probably not productive to go into details (but will do if you ask) as I'm not even entirely convinced of my own argument.  I'm happy to accept the view it is valid.  Thanks for the interesting discussion/problem.

Answer (score 7):

The `block` construct allows you to declare entities such as variables, types, external procedures, etc which are locally known to the block but have no effect to any variables outside of the block.

Example 1:

```
IF (swapxy) THEN
  BLOCK
    REAL (KIND (x)) tmp
    tmp = x
    x = y
    y = tmp
  END BLOCK
END IF
```

Here the variable `tmp` is locally defined to help out with the swap of two variables. Outside of the block, the variable `tmp` is unknown or back its original form if it was defined outside of the block (see next example).

Example 2:

```
F = 254E-2
BLOCK
  REAL F
  F = 39.37
END BLOCK
! F is still equal to 254E-2.
```

The variable `F` is redefined locally to the block but has no effect outside of it.

These kinds of blocks are used to make the code more readable and easier to understand as you don't need to look to the entire subprogram to understand what the locally defined entities are. Furthermore, the compiler knows that these entities are locally defined, so it might do some more optimization.