# When is implicit type declaration ever good?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a colleague who writes Fortran, generally following the F77 standard. I have had to work with some of their source code and I find the use of implicit type declarations (not using `implicit none`) really confusing and frustrating. Their reason for doing so is to "eliminate all of those type declarations at the beginning of my program(s)." In my opinion, this is a poor trade off for ruining readability and comprehension of the program and its many subroutines. Are there any other, more valid, reasons for *not* including `implicit none` in Fortran programs and subroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be entirely clear, relying on implicit typing is frowned upon by many. With good cause. However, there is one case where where some may view implicit typing the lesser of two evils.

Implicit typing allows one to have an object which is of a type whose name is not accessible in a scope:

```
  implicit type(badexample) (d)

  type badexample
    integer :: neverever=4
  end type badexample

  call sub

contains

  subroutine reallybad(badexample)
    integer, optional :: badexample
! With the declaration above we can't declare a local variable of explicit
! type badexample:
!   type(badexample) dontdothis
    print*, dontdothis%neverever
  end subroutine reallybad

end
```

Really, this is a poor excuse to use implicit typing. One which can be avoided by other design choices.

---

Under Fortran 77, of course, one cannot use `implicit none`.

Comment: Truly, don't use implicit typing. I'd say in my answer that there is no excuse to ever use implicit typing if it weren't for the more objective desires of this site. I mean _never_ use implicit typing, even if you have a FORTRAN 77 compiler or the case of this answer. Never.

Comment: if implicit none cannot be use in F77 does one just use explicit type declarations as usual?

Comment: (Modern) good practice even with F77 code is to explicitly declare everything.  Even F77 compilers as they were 35 years ago mostly accepted `implicit none` as a non-standard extension.  Implicit typing doesn't mean explicit typing can't be used.

Comment: I don't fully understand the example you provided, so it's unlikely I'll ever use such an approach =/

Comment: (FWIW, one shouldn't say "implicit typing is evil; everyone knows that" to a colleague. Instead, point out the advantages of using `implicit none`. Yes, `implicit none; integer i` is "more work", but the advantages in the situation `do i=1,5; print*, ix; end do` are clear.)

Comment: Even if you understood my answer, please never use it. However, to explain: the dummy argument `badexample` is a name of a local identifier in the scope. This means that (almost) nothing else in that scope may use that local identifier, including using it as a type in a declaration. This is like how if you have an internal function, or dummy argument, `sin` you don't have access to the intrinsic `sin`. It's just that implicit typing has "higher precedence".

Comment: OK, good answer. My thinking was that the whole, "but look how many lines of code I saved!" argument quit holding water when OS-on-floppy went the way of the dodo bird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214782/discussion-between-osprey-and-francescalus).

Comment: So... implicit typing is confusing and error-prone, but it might be necessary to write code that is even more confusing and error prone. Got it. (Sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: @chw21, decent summary. I refer also to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476018/3157076) I made for bonus confusion. Kids, don't play with implicit typing.

Answer (score 1):

When your code is a stack of punch cards that must not be dropped or brought out of order, methods to reduce line count make sense. In modern time there is no reason for implicit typing.

I had an old guard colleague who could not be dissuaded from using implicit typing. He claimed that using implicit typing for most variables and explicit typing only for those few variables that don't follow Hungarian notation makes these variables stand out more and that helps him to better understand the code.

Use comments for readability. That's what they're there for.

Comment: Comments are not all there is to readability and comprehensible code. That said, I would welcome more comments in the code I've inherited and I'm generally a fan of good commenting.

Comment: Interesting. I figured, wrongly, that punch cards would have been compiled rather than source. My first OS experience was DOS and win3.1, so I know nothing of punch cards.

Comment: Here's a video about punch cards: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KG2M4ttzBnY

Comment: I really wanted to watch him throw them all into the air and yell, "huzzah!"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used punch cards but I usually use implicit none in my Fortran codes as well. Much of my Fortran coding now, however, is just to write a pre-processor or post-processor of data. Things that people use python for now. I know python but my programming skills in python are not that good. So when you're writing 100-300 lines of code only the implicit none can be a pain. I use it so people won't make fun of me but for short utility codes, implicit none buys you little. imho!

Comment: Rest assured, I'd point and laugh if I caught you omitting `implicit none` in even a 10-line code :-)  Sure, for program-lets all it buys you is the time you save trying to figure out the mysterious error at run time which turns out to have been a spelling error at typing time !