# Why can't we define the array size by a variable?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I found that the array size can be defined by parameters but not variables. An example is given below to explain what I am saying.

**1st Example - Not working:**

```
integer :: narr=100
integer, dimension(narr) :: Total
```

**2nd Example - Working:**

```
integer, parameter :: narr=100
integer, dimension(narr) :: Total
```

In the 1st example, I expect the `dimension` can use the variable `narr` as `narr` is defined FIRST. But I realized that this may not be true as the creation of variable may not follow the order of my code lines. Maybe this is only what a person with Python background only would think so.

In the 2nd example, things work perfectly.

I speculate that the difference is related to WHEN the variable and constant are created. Can someone explain the mystery inside it?

Comment: I'm tempted to call this question a duplicate of one like [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45711764/3157076).  Can you read my answer there and see if it explains things?

Comment: As the answer referred to by francescalus shows, there are many possible aspects to your question.  Another possibility which may be related is the "automatic array."  The syntax is simpler than the equivalent ALLOCATABLE, at the expense of weak error recovery facility.

Comment: @francescalus Yes, your post does also help explain the things. But the answer only explains this phenomenon by stating that this is the rule of Fortran. But I want to understand why it would behave like this. I think the memory architecture as pointed out by Raul Laasner is the cause behind this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your examples, since `integer, dimension(narr) :: Total` does not have an `allocatable` or `pointer` attribute, it is either a static array or an automatic array, depending on the context (I'm leaving out assumed shape array because the question is specifically about *defining* arrays). In either case, its size must be a compile time constant or a dummy argument. In the first example, `narr` is neither which makes it invalid Fortran. In order to use `narr` as a non-constant variable to specify the size, you would need to declare `Total` as a dynamic array by including the `allocatable` or `pointer` attribute. This might have a performance penalty depending on the situation, but it allows more flexibility in how and where the array bound is defined.

Here are some of the common ways to define static and dynamic arrays in Fortran:

```
  ! Static
  call test_fixed_size()
  call test_size_parameter()

  ! Dynamic
  call test_allocatable()
  call test_pointer()
  call test_automatic(10)

contains
  subroutine test_fixed_size()
    integer :: array(10)
    array = 1
  end subroutine test_fixed_size

  subroutine test_size_parameter()
    integer, parameter :: size = 10
    integer :: array(size)
    array = 1
  end subroutine test_size_parameter

  subroutine test_allocatable()
    integer, allocatable :: array(:)
    integer :: narr = 100
    allocate(array(narr))
    array = 1
  end subroutine test_allocatable

  subroutine test_pointer()
    integer, pointer :: array(:) => null()
    integer :: narr = 100
    allocate(array(narr))
    array = 1
    deallocate(array)
  end subroutine test_pointer

  subroutine test_automatic(size)
    integer, intent(in) :: size
    integer :: array(size)
    array = 1
  end subroutine test_automatic
end program
```

(I'm leaving out more modern features here such as automatic allocation on assignment.)

Comment: @francescalus Sure, the Fortran standard does not mention stack or heap anywhere. What I meant was more to provide some rationale behind these language rules. For example, static arrays *are* often placed on the stack and thus it makes sense to require that their size be known beforehand. I just thought that thinking in terms of stack and heap helps to remember these rules, even though the actual memory model is up for the compiler and OS to decide. In any case, I removed the confusing bits from the answer.

Comment: I thinking in the early days it was mostly heap, and the arrays were not allocatable back then, the main rational would be if the size is known, then keep it fixed. If it is unknown or needs to be changeable then allocatable, and pointer array only as a last resort if one needs a pointer.

Comment: Not mostly heap, mostly static. In the old days all storage was static. Hence no dynamic arrays, no automatic arrays, no recursion. Fortran compilers can now place automatic arrays on the stack or on the heap and some will do either based on their size.

Comment: Just watched a video about code/static/stack/heap. In example 1, I defined a fixed-size array `Total` whose size cannot be change in runtime (as it is in stack) but the variable `narr` defining the size of that array `Total` can actually be changed during the runtime. So putting these two things together is a contradiction. So the compiler disallow such operation. Am i correct?

Comment: @KenT You are correct in your comment. The compiler will issue an error.